# Simultaneous diagonalization of a set of commuting hermitian 8*8 matrices

Tags: python, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I have four commuting hermitian 8*8 matrices A, B, C, D. The eigenvalues are +1 and -1, each with multiplicity 4. I want to diagonalize these matrices *simultaneously*. Due to the 4-fold degeneracy of each eigenvalue this is not straightforward.

**First question**

- Is there a built-in function for Python in NumPy, SciPy ... to do that?

There seems to be an algorithm which diagonalizes the matrix

X(a,b,c,d) = aD + bB + cC + dD

where a, b, c, d are all non-zero numbers, in our case real such that X is also hermitian. X must have maximal rank i.e. rank(X) = 8, or det(X) != 0.

**Further questions**

- Is there a proof for this algorithm using X?
- Under which further conditions does this algorithm converge?
- How do I have to chose the numbers a, b, c, d?

The code snipped (that works for my purposes) reads

```
import numpy as np    
import scipy as sci   
 

# generates all simultaneous eigenvectors for a list of matrices:
# condition of mutual commuting matrices is not checked        

def simul_eigen_vec_generator(ops):                                                                     
    rands = np.random.randint(1, 100, len(ops))
    rnd_lin_ops = np.sum(rands[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * ops, axis=0)                          
    _, e_vecs = sci.linalg.eig(rnd_lin_ops)    
    for k in range(rnd_lin_ops.shape[0]):    
        e_vec = e_vecs[:, k:k+1].T[0]
        yield e_vec
```